# nnet vs glmer for multilevel logit

Tags: r, regression, multilevel-analysis, nonlinear-regression, multinomial-distribution

I have data where I'm interested in the effect of treatment on individual decisions: Options 1, 2, & 3. Individuals made multiple decisions (level 1) in groups (level 2).

I want to know the effect of treatment on selecting a particular option over not selecting that option. To do this, I dichotomized each option into 3 variables: Option 1 or not Option 1, Option 2 or not Option 2, Option 3 or not Option 3.

I tried to run a binomial regression using glmer: e.g., `glmer(Option1 ~ Predictors + (1|Level_1) + (1|Level_2), family=binomial)`, which did not converge.

I ran the same analysis using nnet::multinom: e.g., `multinom(Option1 ~ Predictors, random=~ 1| Level_1/Level_2, family=binomial)`. This did converge and gave sensible results.

What's going on? Is it justifiable to use multinom instead of glmer on the dichotomized data?

Any insight would be appreciated!